# What may be the causes of the error 0x80010108 (The object invoked has disconnected from its clients)?

Tags: c++, com

In C++ program the call to method of coclass returns the error 0x80010108 (The object invoked has disconnected from its clients). What may be the causes of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an RPC error, you'll see it when you use out-of-process COM.  It tells you that the server .exe stopped running.  It probably bombed.  Or decided to exit even though there were still active interface references.  That could be a reference count problem.  Or improper use of CAtlModule::Lock().  Etcetera, I can only guess.  Debug the server with Tools + Attach to Process and find out why it decided to quit.

Answer (score 0):

This error is raised from a COM generated proxy object, so your server object (the one being called) is living in another apartment, ether out-of-proc or on another thread in the current process. Something very bad has happened to this apartment so it was terminated and now the COM stub living there cannot be reached by the proxy (via RPC or message pump).