# Unable to start program error in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Whenever I try to start my program from Visual C++ 2010 Express IDE in debug mode, I get the following error in a message box.

```
Unable to start program <program name>
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients
```

Note that I am using the [Visual Leak Detector](http://vld.codeplex.com/) also for the first time, maybe it has something to do with it.

Comment: What happens if you disable Visual Leak Detector?

Comment: "discconnected from its clients" sounds like some COM stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate for this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346728/what-may-be-the-causes-of-the-error-0x80010108-the-object-invoked-has-disconnec